# A generic class that lets me have different return types (Java)

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

Today I've been working with generic/parametric types in java () exercising my polymorphism understanding but since quite some time now I've been having an issue where I would have a generic class with a single method that returns a value, the reason is because I want to be able to call a method and by context been able to have different return types

```
class dummy <E>{
    E value;
    public E getValue(){
         return value;
    }
class dummy1 extends dummy<E>{
    int value;
    public int getValue(){
         return int;
    }
class dummy2 extends dummy<E>{
    boolean value;
    public boolean getValue(){
         return boolean;
    }
```

Is this possible? I'm not really sure if even this is the correct way of doing this kind of thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that in Java primitives, such as `int` and `boolean`, cannot be generic arguments.

You need to swap these for equivalent reference types: `Integer` and `Boolean`.

Also `E` is scoped to the `dummy` class. You will need to provide the type argument to the superclass.

```
class Dummy<E> {
    private E value;
    public Dummy(E value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
    public E getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}
class Dummy1 extends Dummy<Integer> {
    public Dummy1(Integer value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
}
class Dummy2 extends Dummy<E> {
    public Dummy2(Boolean value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
abstract class Dummy<E> {
    public abstract E getValue();
}
class ReferenceDummy<E> extends Dummy<E> {
    private final E value;
    public Dummy1(E value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
    @Override public E getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}
class Dummy1 extends Dummy<Integer> {
    private int value;
    public Dummy1(int value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
    @Override public Integer getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}
class Dummy2 extends Dummy<Boolean> {
    private boolean value;
    public Dummy1(boolean value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
    @Override public Boolean getValue() {
         return value;
    }
}
```

Note that, say, `boolean getValue()` cannot override `Boolean getValue()` for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have two questions. Why do I have to add parameters to this Dummy function and why there is no return value in its function signature?

Comment: @Hackermann I've added to my answer in a number of edits. Do you mean in the first example? Those are constructors to receive a value for `value`.

Comment: When I tried to use the first version of your solution it asks for a constructor Dummy<Integer>(). Is this what you were refering to when you said  "Also E is scoped to the dummy class. You will need to provide the type argument to the superclass."?

Comment: @Hackermann `E` is declared in `Dummy` and so only makes sense within `Dummy`. When you reference `Dummy` you need to specify (or imply) what the parameter should be. This includes in the `extends` clause, constructing a new instance of the generic class and declaring a reference to an instance. In some places it can be inferred by the language, for instance `Dummy<String> dummyString = new Dummy<>("some text");`.